# Do triggers keep order in bulk insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that i will be doing bulk inserts ordered in a particular order into. On this table there is a trigger that will update a number of different tables. I know that a trigger only runs once for bulk inserts. But my question is does the trigger keep the order that the inserts are done or would i need to ORDER the data at the start of the trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ordering guarantee for selecting from any table, without specifying an ORDER BY. So, You need to order data in `inserted` and `deleted` temp tables in your trigger. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183974/are-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables-guaranteed-to-return-their-records-in-th)

Comment: thanks Alexander, was looking online for ages and could not find that anywhere!